# Tool To Generate Data Migration Script From Table A To Table B In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

During our SQL Server database deployments, we create a temporary table which contains the new desired state of data for a particular table. We then merge the temp table into the target table (we actually use individual insert, update and delete statements, but that's probably not relevant). The inserts/updates/deletes performed are captured and written out to a log.

We would like to be able to report on what changes would be applied by a deployment, without actually applying them. This is currently done by rolling back the transaction at the end of the above process. This doesn't feel particularly great though.

Now what we are thinking of doing is, instead of performing the changes and rolling them back, we will generate a migration script for the table (generate some SQL code that performs the necessary inserts, updates and deletes). If we want to do the actual deployment, this code will be dynamically executed. If not, the code will just be printed to a log.

It shouldn't take long to put together some code which can generate migration scripts for two specified tables, but I first wanted to verify that there isn't already an existing tool which can do this?

Searching on Google, I can find lots of talk about migrating whole databases, but nothing about generating a data migration script to effectively merge one table into another.

So my question is, does anyone know of such a tool?

Comment: What solution did you settle on? If you are using insert, update and delete statements, can't you just save off that script before you execute it, as this is effectively the record of what has been applied?

Comment: @DavidAtkinson What we're doing for now is similar to what you describe. We select into an Actions_Planned table variable, including all the existing values in the target table and new values in the source table) based on a join between the source and target. We then print out the planned actions from this table variable including the old and new column values. Then if we want to actually perform the changes, instead of joining the source and target table, we join the Actions_Planned table to the target table, and perform exactly the actions we said we were going to perform.

Comment: We also use an OUTPUT clause to populate an Actions_Performed table variable which can then be used to print what changes were actually made. The reason we use the Actions_Planned table to drive the changes rather than the source table, is so that we aren't duplicating the logic of determining whether to insert/update/delete/do nothing, and therefore remove the risk of reporting one thing and doing something else.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It's always interesting to know how problems are solved in different ways!

Answer (score 0):

There are several data compare tools like:

- SQL Data Compare from Red Gate
- SQL Server Data Tools
- dbForge Data Compare from Devart

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks. I was ideally looking for something like a stored-procedure that I could call within our SQL scripts. So we could keep the majority of our existing process where we create a temp table containing the desired state, but then use a procedure to generate the migration script automatically. RedGate SQL Data Compare does look interesting though, as does the data compare tool in SSDT.